# Norm of $xy$ equals norm of $yx$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given is that $\|y\| = \|x\|$,

Is it true that $x^Ty = \|xy\|$ and $y^Tx = \|xy\|$

If the things above are true, is this also true $\|xy\| = \|yx\|$?

And why or why not ?

Comment: what are $x$ and $y$ and how is $xy defined$? (what is the multiplication structure$?

Comment: That's not an answer.

Comment: I changed the post

Comment: Still not an answer to SiddharthBhat's question. In what kind of space do $x$ and $y$ live? How do you multiply them? What is the norm here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you mean $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^d$.

Then $xy$ is not a defined object.

There is however the inner product of $x$ and $y$, which is equal to:

$x^T y$ and is in fact a scalar, i.e. an element in $\mathbb{R}$.

Since the transpose of a scalar is just the scalar itself, we have:

$(x^Ty)^T=y^Tx$ i.e. the scalar product is commutative.

Note that the norm is only defined for vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$, not for scalars, so the notation:

$\lVert x^Ty \rVert$ strictly speaking does not make sense, nor does $\lVert y^Tx \rVert$.

And since $xy$ is not a defined object, then $\lVert xy \rVert$ definitely does not make any sense.

So in short, the answer to your questions are all no, since the equations in question do not make sense.

Sure, we have $x^Ty=y^Tx \implies |x^Ty|=|y^Tx|$ where the bars here are absolute value and NOT the norm, but this is equivalent to saying something like $2=2 \implies |2|=|2|$, i.e. utterly trivial.

I hope this clears something up for you. I apologize if this mostly seems like pedantry to you, but sometimes you have to keep track of the details in order to avoid getting confused.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I can say that $x^Ty = y^Tx$

Comment: Yes, that is correct, as I explained above. However, the norm is not defined for either side of that equation, even though the absolute value is -- the norm and the absolute value are similar but not the same.